# How to initialize struct fields which reference each other

Tags: rust

I currently want to define a struct for a [Piston](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/piston) game using GamerIterator:

```rust
pub struct MyGame<'a> {
    game_window: GameWindowGLFW,
    game_iter: GameIterator<'a, GameWindowGLFW>,
    //...
}
```

The `GameIterator` is generic in the `GameWindow` and its lifetime. I want to tell the compiler that it has the same lifetime as the field "game_window"/"the whole struct" and leave out the lifetime for the struct.

I also have difficulties initializing this:

```
MyGame {
    game_window: GameWindowGLFW::new(GameWindowSettings {/*...*/},
    game_iter: GameIterator::new(&mut game_window, &game_iter_settings), // game_window cannot be used here
    //...
}
```

I think that I can work around the initialization issue by using `Option<GameIterator<...>>` and an init() method, but I would like to avoid this because I can guarantee that `game_iter` is present after `new()` finishes.

What is the idiomatic way to write this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not only is there an issue with initialization, there could also be issues with destruction, if `GameIterator` implemented `Drop`: the compiler would have to know that it needs to destruct `game_iter` before `game_window`, otherwise `game_window` would have a reference to a destroyed `GameWindowGLFW` while running its `drop()` method.

There's no way to pass the lifetime of the struct itself as a lifetime argument. The only thing you can do is remove the `game_window` field from `MyGame` and pass a `GameWindowGLFW` instance to `MyGame`'s initializer. If you want to encapsulate this so that the user doesn't need to create a `GameWindowGLFW`, you could write a method that creates a `GameWindowGLFW` and a `MyGame` on the stack and calls a closure that accepts a `MyGame` argument only.

```
pub struct MyGame<'a> {
    game_iter: GameIterator<'a, GameWindowGLFW>,
    //...
}

impl<'a> MyGame<'a> {
    fn new(game_window: &'a mut GameWindowGLFW) -> MyGame<'a> {
        MyGame {
            game_iter: GameIterator { game_window: game_window },
        }
    }
}

fn start_game(callback: |game: &mut MyGame|) {
    let mut game_window = GameWindowGLFW;
    let mut game = MyGame::new(&mut game_window);
    callback(&mut game);
}

fn main() {
    start_game(|game| {
        /* use game here */
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the reason for this, but it is still strange that it does not work...Also can't think of a safe and generic solution the compiler could easily verify, all depends on the dependencies and initialization/destruction order.