# Initialize a field of a struct using another field of the same struct

Tags: rust

Below I have a struct `SplitByChars`.

```
struct SplitByChars<'a> {
    seperator: &'a Seperator,
    string: String,
    chars_iter: std::str::Chars<'a>,
}

impl<'a> SplitByChars<'a> {
    fn new<S>(seperator: &'a Seperator, string: S) -> SplitByChars where S: Into<String> {
        SplitByChars {
            seperator: seperator,
            string: string.into(),
            chars_iter: self.string.chars(), // ERROR: I cannot use self here!
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement a `new` static function for it. In particular, I would like to return a `SplitByChars` instance whose `chars_iter` field is initialized using the previously initialized `string` field of the same instance. To do that, I am currently trying to access the same field using `self.string`, but I am getting an error.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I do it?

You can't. Unless I misunderstand your question, this is the same problem as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269597/how-to-initialize-struct-fields-which-reference-each-other). Structs generally cannot have references into themselves.

Comment: Ok, I understand the design. However, is there any help with the design of the structs that needs to reference to itself? How can I redesign my struct to fulfill this need?

Answer (score -2):

I think you're making things overly complicated. Splitting a string at specific chars can be done with:

```
let s: String = "Tiger in the snow".into();
for e in s.split(|c| c == 'e') {
    println!("{}", e);
}
```

Output:

```
Tig
r in th
 snow
```

There are several variations of the split function to suit various needs.

Comment: I'm not asking for spliting the strings, and I think there're cases that you'll need to reference yourself in the struct.