# How to design a struct when I need to reference to itself

Tags: rust

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31794503/using-self-in-new-constructor) tells me that Rust cannot take reference to itself in a struct.

So my question would become: how to design a struct when I need to reference to itself?

We might take this struct as an example:

```
struct SplitByChars<'a> {
    seperator: &'a Seperator,
    string: String,
    chars_iter: std::str::Chars<'a>,
}

impl<'a> SplitByChars<'a> {
    fn new<S>(seperator: &'a Seperator, string: S) -> SplitByChars where S: Into<String> {
        SplitByChars {
            seperator: seperator,
            string: string.into(),
            chars_iter: self.string.chars(), // error here: I cannot use self (of course, static method)
        }
    }
}
```

I used `chars_iter` to provide an interface of iterable string splitting.

(This is just an example, so I'd like to know about a more general idea on designing the struct, not specially in this splitting case. Moreover, no std's split.)

Answer (score 1):

You can’t. Rust’s iterators are not designed to be used that way. Rearrange things so that you *don’t* need to store the string inside the iterator. It should only have a reference.

Comment: Let's think about the design here:
`let sep = Seperator::new(",:; ");`
`let split_iter = sep.split(mystring);`
However, if I hold the string inside the seperator, when I want to get a new split_iter2 with `let split_iter2 = sep.split(mystring2);`, then the split_iter1 will be invalidated, which will cause the `does not live long enough` error.

Answer (score 1):

While a field cannot reference another field within a struct, you can usually
achieve what you need by **moving** them. It works by having one field as data
and another field as an `Option` containing some struct taking that data by value 
(and implementing some trait of your interest).

You can find the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32046805/5222798) implementing an itetaror adaptor,
where the data was a `HashMap` and the `Option` contained the map's `IntoIter`.
During the iteration once the access to the map was no longer needed, it was
*moved* into `IntoIter` using `std::mem::replace`.

However, in your specific case there is no method in `std` that would
create `Chars` iterator by *consuming* the `String` (i.e. using `self` as an argument). You would have to implement it yourself.